# Redefine navigation keys for JSSOR?

Tags: javascript, jssor

On our webpage we would like to host two JSSOR image slider controls side-by-side.

This works OK, but both controls answer to key navigation synchronously.
We didn't find in documentation how we could redefine key bindings for this slider.

Is there any simple way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set $ArrowKeyNavigation to false.
And detect key press manually, call jssor_slider1.$Prev() or jssor_slider1.$Next().